# PHP OCI8 bind (unknown number of) params for 'IN' statement

Tags: php, sql, oracle-call-interface

For SQL IN clause, how do I handle an unknown number of parameters when binding SQL with PHP OCI8?

For example, given the following query

```
select * from table1
where id > :id_1
and id in (:id_array_of_unknown_size)
```

and the array of variables to bind

```
$bind_array = array(
    ':id_1' => '1',
    ': id_array_of_unknown_size' => array('7','2','5',),
);
```

Also its important to note that in my particular situation the input `array($bind_array)` may or may not contain a sub-array for the bind element. It could just as well be the following

```
select * from table1
where id > :id_1
and id !=  :id_2
```

and

```
$bind_array = array(
    ':id_1' => '1',
    ':id_2' => '5',
);
```

Comment: can you bind to IN in oci? I think in PDO you cannot bind to IN

Answer (score 4):

One way is the binding of a small fixed number of values in an IN clause like described in the docs of [oci_bind_by_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php#example-2202). There is also a solution to bind multiple conditions with a variable number of values.

```
<?php
$ids = array(
    103,
    104
);

$conn         = oci_pconnect($user, $pass, $tns);
// Using ORACLE table() function to get the ids from the subquery
$sql          = 'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(:ids))';
$stmt         = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
// Create collection of numbers. Build in type for strings is ODCIVARCHAR2LIST, but you can also create own types.
$idCollection = oci_new_collection($conn, 'ODCINUMBERLIST', 'SYS');

// Maximum length of collections of type ODCINUMBERLIST is 32767, maybe you should check that!
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $idCollection->append($id);
}

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':ids', $idCollection, -1, SQLT_NTY);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
oci_fetch_all($stmt, $return);
oci_free_statement($stmt);

oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should bind an array with another function - oci_bind_array_by_name

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-array-by-name.

you cant just replace :variable with array objects by oci_bind_by_name
http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php